# setting up value to use it as identifier

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

what am i missing here. cant seem to work this method.

```
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6");
    System.out.println("original list: " + numbers);
    List<Integer> even = numbers.stream()
                                .map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s))
                                .filter(number -> number % 2 == 0)
                                .collect();
    System.out.println("processed list, only even numbers: " + even);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your complete context but still my few cents:

1. You don't require second if loop

`if (wrapper.getAttrKey().equalsIgnoreCase("BetterID") && !StringUtils...`

because your are just checking the same condition (which you did in first if loop) and then retrieving the value. So removed that duplicate piece.

```
    List<CompareDecisionResponse> compareResponse= new 
    ArrayList<CompareDecisionResponse>();

    for (Answer singleAnswer : answer){
    String identifier = "";
     String name = "";
    boolean identifierFound = false;

    Response fileName = new Response(); //Response is another class.
    name = fileName.getFileName();

    for(AttrValWrapper wrapper: singleAnswer.getAttrValContainer().getAttrValWrapper()){
        if(wrapper.getAttrKey().equalsIgnoreCase("BetterID")){
            wrapper.setAttrVal(name); // setting up value.
            identifier = name;
            identifierFound = true;
        }

       if (!identifierFound && wrapper.getAttrKey().equalsIgnoreCase("MemoryId")&&!StringUtils.isEmpty(wrapper.getAttrVal())){
            identifier = wrapper.getAttrVal();
        }
    }
```

2. fixed variable name from `IdentifierFound` to `identifierFound`